# JS Prettier Sort Imports By Path?

Tags: reactjs, prettier

I am using prettier formatting to sort my imports while using a RegEx. I'm a little stuck/confused on whether its possible to be more specific about paths when sorting.

For example:

```
import reminderfrom '../App/xxx/xxxreminder';
import '../Common/common.scss';
```

I currently have my prettierrc using the following RegEx importOrder

```
"importOrder": ["^[./]"],
```

If I wanted to have my ../Common scripts come before my ../App scripts, is that possible?

Comment: A suggestion: How about utilizing [`eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort) instead? It provides exactly what you wanted, though you have to add extra dependencies in the process...

Comment: I'm a big proponent of good code styling, but I wonder if this goes a little bit too far.. Just my opinion of course.